# How to use code from a third party python class in a repo when deploying a lambda function using AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, repo

I have a repo, let's call it `3rdPartyRepo`. Within that repo lies a python file, call it `PyFile.py`, and within that file, there is a function, `functionToUseForLambda`, which I want to use as code for my lambda function.

Given that my AWS CDK deployment code lies in another repo, what is the best way to set `functionToUseForLambda` as the code for a lambda function when defining a stack? That is, what should I put in the "<CODE_GOES_HERE>" section for the code snipped below?

```
class RawDataStack(core.Stack):
    ...
    handler = Function(self, "initial-load-lambda",
                       runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
                       code=<CODE_GOES_HERE>,
                       handler="test.lambda_handler",
                       environment={"BUCKET": raw_bucket.bucket_name})
```

Thanks in advance!